# C# . net getting active subscribers for a list (campaign- monitor)

Tags: campaign-monitor

I'm new to the CM API and am using the .net library.  In my code below I'm looping through each client in the account, and then each list under the client.  This is working fine.  For the next step I'd like to loop through the active subscribers in each list but am stuck there,

```
AuthenticationDetails auth = new ApiKeyAuthenticationDetails("3efa70e3918fc3e6282eb2ef053a9b0c29247f180e78d8b1");
var general = new General(auth);
var clients = general.Clients();
foreach (BasicClient c in clients)
{
 var clientID = c.ClientID;
 var cl = new Client(auth, c.ClientID);
 var list = cl.Lists();
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("----------List Details-------------"));
  var ListID = "";
            foreach (var listItem in list)
            {
                ListID = listItem.ListID;
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("List ID  - {0}", listItem.ListID));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("List Name  - {0}", listItem.Name));

                ListDetail details = cl.HttpGet<ListDetail>(
                string.Format("/lists/{0}.json", ListID), null);


                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ConfirmationSuccessPage  - {0}", details.ConfirmationSuccessPage));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ConfirmedOptIn  - {0}", details.ConfirmedOptIn));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("UnsubscribePage  - {0}", details.UnsubscribePage));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("UnsubscribeSetting  - {0}", details.UnsubscribeSetting));

                ListStats Liststats = cl.HttpGet<ListStats>(string.Format("/lists/{0}/stats.json", ListID), null);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total Active Subscribers - {0}", Liststats.TotalActiveSubscribers));


            }
}
```

Comment: Stuck on this exact issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListDetail details = cl.HttpGet<ListDetail>(
string.Format("/lists/{0}/active.json", ListID), null);
```

Comment: It's mentioned in the API documention. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/lists/#active-subscribers